# Quantikz: equally sized gate boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, quantikz

I am composing a quantum circuit diagram using the LaTeX package Quantikz. My problem is that I want to have some gates equally sized, but don't manage to find a solution. Take this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}[column sep=5pt, row sep={20pt,between origins}]
  & \gate{H} & \qw \\
  & \gate{Y^\dagger} & \qw \\
  & \gate{R_z^\dagger} & \qw
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

it produces the following output.

[image]

You see that all these gates have different width and height. How can I make these equally sized? In particular, I was to make the larger gates (Y and Rz) smaller and reduce the white space inside the boxes to have its box the same size as the H-gate.

I tried setting the `scale`, `minimum size`, `text width`, etc. But then, the wires don't connect to the gates anymore, e.g., adding

```
\tikzset{operator/.append style={text width={width("$R_z^\dagger$")}}}
```

before `\begin{document}` results in

[image]

I hope someone can provide a solution, thank you!

Comment: You can specify the width of a `gate` by the second argument, e.g. `\gate[][1cm]{H}` sets the width to 1cm.

Comment: Yes, but `\gate[][xx]{H}` only increases the gate width if `xx` is larger than `minimum size`, it does not have any effect if you choose `xx` smaller than `minimum size`. Neither can does setting `minimum size` to a smaller value have any effect.
Rather than enlarging H, I would like to make the boxes of Y and Rz smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a cheat:

```
\begin{quantikz}[column sep=5pt, row sep={20pt,between origins}]
  & \gate{H} & \qw \\
  & \gate{Y^\dagger} & \qw \\
  & \gate[style={inner xsep=-4pt}]{R_z^\dagger} & \arrow[arrows]{ll}
\end{quantikz}
```

You control the width however you like. Then, assuming your gates have a background colour (i.e. you're not using the transparent option), you can draw a line of double length to go behind the gate, so you don't see the gaps.

If I ever have time, I'll look at removing the need for that...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this works. Do you have a fix if the gate is immediately followed by a gate or the target of a CNOT gate?