# Quantikz formatting gate boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, quantikz

I'm trying to draw a circuit in [`quantikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/quantikz) and using examples from the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
& \gate[style={inner xsep=-5pt}]{H} & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \qw \\
& \qw & \qw & \gate[2,style={inner xsep=-5pt, rotate=-90}]{R_z(-\theta/2)} & \qw & \gate[2,style={inner xsep=-5pt, rotate=-90}]{R_z(\theta/2)} & \meter{} \\
& \qw & \targ{} & \qw & \targ{} & \qw & \meter{}
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

How do I set the gate box size by default using `style={inner xsep=-5pt}`? I tried the answers in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/564763/) but they only show how to do it for individual gates. Is it also possible to remove the white spaces between the gates and wires (see `H` gate below)?

I also want to rotate the text and box of some gates by 90 deg counterclockwise - I tried using a `style={rotate=-90}` and `style={rotate=270}` command but this doesn't do anything.

[image]

### Edit:

Following Simon Dispa's suggestion, the following code

```
\begin{quantikz}
    & \gate{H} & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \qw \\
    & \qw & \qw 
    & \gate[2,style={inner ysep=-2pt, inner xsep=-12pt}, label style={rotate=90}]{R_z(-\theta/2)} & \qw 
    & \gate[2,style={inner ysep=-2pt, inner xsep=-12pt}, label style={rotate=90}]{R_z(\theta/2)} & \meter{} \\
    & \qw & \targ{} & \qw & \targ{} & \qw & \meter{}
\end{quantikz}
```

gives

[image]

Why are there big spaces between the wires and boxes? How do I make the boxes the same height and width?

### Edit 2:

I modified Simon Dispa's answer so that the `Rz` gates are connected to the lower two wires. But I can't get rid of the gap using `\arrow[arrows]{ll}`

```
\tikzset{
    operator/.append style={draw,fill=blue!10, text height = 50pt, text width = 20pt},
}  
\begin{quantikz}
& \gate[style={text height = 20pt},label style={cyan}]{H} & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \qw  & \qw \\
& \qw & \qw 
& \gate[2, label style={black, rotate=90,}]{R_z(-\theta/2)} &  \arrow[arrows]{ll}
& \gate[2, label style={black,rotate=90}]{R_z(\theta/2)} &  \arrow[arrows]{ll} & \meter{} \\
& \qw & \targ{} & \arrow[arrows]{ll} & \targ{} & \arrow[arrows]{ll}  & \qw & \meter{}
\end{quantikz}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\gate`  accept a tikz  node formatting key as `label style`  in an optional argument and also accept a second key for formatting other elements of the display as `style`, to style the box.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}    
    
\begin{quantikz}
        & \gate[style={fill=red!20,inner xsep=1ex},label style={cyan}]{H} & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \qw \\
        & \qw & \qw 
        & \gate[label style={black, rotate=90}][0pt][11ex]{R_z(-\theta/2)}{}{} & \qw 
        & \gate[style={fill=red!20, inner ysep=3.5ex,   inner xsep=0ex},label style={black, rotate=90}]{R_z(\theta/2)} & \meter{} \\
        & \qw & \targ{} & \qw & \targ{} & \qw & \meter{}
    \end{quantikz}
    
\end{document}
```

For  global styling use  `tikzset`. For example

```
\tikzset{
    gg label/.append style={rotate=90},
}
```

will rotate all the gate labels (page #11 of the manual)

**Update** after follow-up question.

You can modify the already defined `operator` style to have a new global default.

But reducing the white space inside the boxes, it makes
the wires are no longer connected to the  gates.

There is a nice fix. See [Quantikz: equally sized gate boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565116/161015)

You can draw a line of double length to go behind the gate, so you don't see the gaps. (Assuming your gates have a background color i.e. you're not using the transparent option).

[image: e]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
    

\tikzset{
    operator/.append style={draw,fill=blue!10, text height = 50pt, text width = 20pt},
}
    
\begin{quantikz}
    & \gate[style={text height = 20pt},label style={cyan}]{H} & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \qw  & \qw \\
    & \qw & \qw 
    & \gate[label style={black, rotate=90,}]{R_z(-\theta/2)} &  \arrow[arrows]{ll}
    & \gate[label style={black,rotate=90}]{R_z(\theta/2)} &  \arrow[arrows]{ll} & \meter{} \\
    & \qw & \targ{} & \qw & \targ{} & \qw  & \qw & \meter{}
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Using the same technique for a 2-wires gates:

[image: f]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
    

\tikzset{
    operator/.append style={draw,fill=blue!10, text height = 50pt, text width = 20pt},
}
    
\begin{quantikz}
    & \gate[style={text height = 20pt},label style={cyan}]{H} & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \qw  & \qw \\
    & \qw & \qw 
    & \gate[label style={black,rotate=90}, wires=2]{R_z(-\theta/2)} &  \arrow[arrows]{ll}
    & \gate[label style={black,rotate=90}, wires=2]{R_z(\theta/2)}  &  \arrow[arrows]{ll} & \meter{} \\
    &\qw  & \targ{} &  & \targ{} \arrow[arrows]{ll} &   & \arrow[arrows]{ll}& \meter{}
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Or, with same result and a simpler code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}   

\begin{document}    
    
\tikzset{
    operator/.append style={draw,fill=blue!10, text height = 50pt, text width = 20pt},
}
    
\begin{quantikz}
    & \gate[style={text height = 20pt},label style={cyan}]{H} & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \ctrl{2} & \qw  & \qw \\
    & &         
    & \gate[label style={black,rotate=90}, wires=2]{R_z(-\theta/2)} &  
    & \gate[label style={black,rotate=90}, wires=2]{R_z(\theta/2)}  &    \meter{}\vqwexplicit{2-1}{2-7} \\
    &  & \targ{} &  & \targ{}  &                                    &    \meter{}\vqwexplicit{3-1}{3-7}
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```